# How to make a page react after insert the correct password?

Tags: html, reactjs, passwords

I made a login page on my computer but I don't know how to make it react after login. I am trying to make a website that people can send messages to each other.
I typed in this:

```
<html>

        <!-- Button to open the modal login form -->
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">Login</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="id01" class="modal">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'"
class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content -->
  <form class="modal-content animate" action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="https://clipground.com/images/img_avatar2-png-2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <label for="friends"><b>Username</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="friends" required>
    </div>
      <label for="keep secrets"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="keep secrets" required>
     <div class="container">
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>

      <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
       <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
       <span class="keep secrets">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of application, a lot more complicated than a single page, i recommend you search for some tutorias like on youtube .-.

This is a good link https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/09/16/react-redux-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example